# 4 IR sensors on Arduino pro micro. 2 are working other aren't

Tags: arduino-ide, pwm, arduino-pro-micro

```
#include <Keyboard.h>
int IRpin = 5;
int IRpin2 = 6;
int IRpin3 = 8;
int IRpin4 = 9;
int led = 13;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //start the serial port
  Keyboard.begin();
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  float volts = analogRead(IRpin);
  Serial.println("volts1:");
  Serial.println(volts);
  delay(1000);
  if (volts>500.00){
    Keyboard.press(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
  }
  float voltss = analogRead(IRpin2);
  Serial.println("volts2:");
  Serial.println(voltss);
  delay(1000);
  if (voltss>600.00){
    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
  }
  float voltsss = analogRead(IRpin3);
  Serial.println("volts3:");
  Serial.println(voltsss);
  delay(1000);
  if (voltsss > 500.00) {
    Keyboard.press(KEY_UP_ARROW);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
  }
  float voltssss = analogRead(IRpin4);
  Serial.println("volts4:");
  Serial.println(voltssss);
  delay(500);
  if (voltssss > 600.00) {
    Keyboard.press(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
  }
}
```

I connected 4 IR infrared sensors to Pro micro and only 2 of them are working. The other 2 are sending random values. 
Connection for all 4 IR sensors.:
IR VCC->Arduino VCC
IR GND -> Arduino GND
Output-> 5,6,8,9

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Pin 5 is not analog pins.

On the pro-micro only pins A0-5 and D4, D6, D8-10, D12 can convert an analog voltage to a value.

Just use the A0-5 pins instead, as that will work on any Arduino.